# How to dynamically add text when jQuery function is open

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a read less / read more toggle switch on my site. It works great, however when it's open ( the text is not hidden ) I want the link text "Read More" to say "Read Less" I'm new at jQuery and looking for a simple solution.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="survey_text">
  Always visable text
</div>
<h3 class="read-more-toggle">Read More</h3>
 <div class="read-more-content">
  <div class="survey_text">
    Hidden text that is toggled open
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Hide the extra content initially, using JS so that if JS is disabled, no problemo.
$('.read-more-content').addClass('hide');

// Set up the toggle.
$('.read-more-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.read-more-content').toggleClass('hide');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use the jQuery text() function.

Answer (score 1):

Add the alternate text as a `data-` attribute:

```
<h3 class="read-more-toggle" data-alt-text="Read less">Read More</h3>
```

And get that text in your JS:

```
$('.read-more-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var text = element.text();

    element
        .text( element.data('alt-text') )
        .data('alt-text', text)
        .next('.read-more-content').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: While it is a good solution, I fear for cross-browser compatibility issues.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija - No issues. Works perfectly all the way back to IE6.

Comment: @joellustigman It's actually reversed of what it should be. When the page loads it says 'read more' and all the content is showing and when I hit the text it says 'read less' and hides the content.